Failure to install "RcppArrayFire" package in R because of "This package has a configure script, It probably needs manual configuration..."
I'm trying to install the package "RcppArrayFire" in R v4.3.2.
After having gone round in circles following multiple attempts at various possible ways of installing a package in R, I'm completely stuck and out of ideas.
"RcppArrayFire" is a package designed to import the ArrrayFire library environment (a C/C++ wrapper for CPU/Cuda/OpenCL backends, see https://arrayfire.org/docs/index.htm#gsc.tab=0), useful for parallel computing. Since R doesn't have a native equivalent or an equivalent from an external library, I decided to install "RcppArrayFire" package (developped in 2019) in R v4.3.2 (a lot more recent).
Software configuration:

R v4.3.2 installed with Rtools 43, "devtools", "Rcpp" and "drat" packages functional
ArrayFire v3.6.1 installed and functional with proper environment declared in system variables)
OS Windows 7 SP1 (for a lot of software reasons, please do not ask why I'm not under Windows 10 or Linux, I may explain later)

At https://github.com/daqana/rcpparrayfire/ are few lines for installing the package "RcppArrayFire", but they fail.
After loading "devtools", "Rcpp" and "drat" libraries in R (with no error message), I try:

drat::addRepo("daqana")
install.packages("RcppArrayFire")

But I receive the error message:

Warning: unable to access index for repository https://daqana.github.io/drat/bin/windows/contrib/4.3:
  cannot open URL 'https://daqana.github.io/drat/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES'
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘RcppArrayFire’
installing the source package ‘RcppArrayFire’

trying URL 'https://daqana.github.io/drat/src/contrib/RcppArrayFire_0.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/gzip' length 62912 bytes (61 KB)
downloaded 61 KB

* installing *source* package 'RcppArrayFire' ...
** using staged installation

   **********************************************
   WARNING: this package has a configure script
         It probably needs manual configuration
   **********************************************


** libs
using C++ compiler: 'G__~1.EXE (GCC) 12.3.0'
using C++11
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/R/R-43~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/R/R-4.3.2/library/Rcpp/include'   -I"C:/Rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c RcppArrayFire.cpp -o RcppArrayFire.o
RcppArrayFire.cpp:23:10: fatal error: RcppArrayFire.h: No such file or directory
   23 | #include <RcppArrayFire.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [C:/R/R-43~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf:272: RcppArrayFire.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RcppArrayFire'
* removing 'C:/R/R-4.3.2/library/RcppArrayFire'

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUtJFAZ\downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("RcppArrayFire") :
  installation of package ‘RcppArrayFire’ had non-zero exit status

The message "RcppArrayFire.cpp:23:10: fatal error: RcppArrayFire.h: No such file or directory" is related to the inability of the g++ compiler to find a header cited for compiling a CPP files from the source of "RcppArrayFire" archive whch R has downloaded during the attempt to install. it.
I verified inside the archive, and both the CPP and the header file are inside, in 'src' and 'include' folders respectively.
The error message starts with a: "WARNING: this package has a configure script. It probably needs manual configuration..."
I discovered via "learning by doing" that by adding the absolute paths of the header inside the CPP at the #include line will 'solve partially' the problem. But it will be rolled out to all headers used by "RcppArrayFire" during the attempt of R to compile it from source (there are more than 10 places to modify) and all the headers used by the ArrayFire shared DLL of ArrayFire (more than 30 references).
So I was forced to unzip the source file of "RcppArrayFire" downloaded by R in the local Temp folder, and modify one by one manually all the file with the correct absolute path for the headers, and the compiling process continued up to some point which was dramatic for the compilation, because of too much error messages (related to bad export of a lot of types).
Maybe "RcppArrayFire" was intended for Linux development (and so for R under Linux), but nowhere this is specified in the GitHub of the package by its authors (Kazuki Fukui and Ralf Stubner).
I tried even to add the absolute path of the ArrayFire library (as they specified on the GitHub:
"RcppArrayFire uses the unified backend of ArrayFire. If you have installed ArrayFire in a non-standard directory, you can use the configure argument --with-arrayfire:

install.packages("RcppArrayFire", configure.args = "--with-arrayfire=/opt/arrayfire")"

even if I installed it in the default folder proposed by the setup of ArrayFire. Nothing changed...
I have no idea how it is possible that a piece of software which was 'functional' few years ago, stops to work in a more recent version of R/Rcpp/Rtools (which normally cancel a lot of previous bug).
I may try to be "time reversal" by installing a R version from 2019-2020, and implicitly try to create the development environment via the corresponding versions of devtools/Rtools/Rcpp. But I know by practice that R is awful regarding this strategy (I may encounter a lot of problems JUST at this level, even before trying to install "RcppArrayFire" library.
Last but not the least, after unzipping the source file of "RcppArrayFire" in the folder 'C:\R\R local repository src\RcppArrayFire", I tried to install the "RcppArrayFire" from this folder, with all CPP modified to point for #include... to the correct absolute path, via the command:
> install("C:/R/R local repository src/RcppArrayFire")
or 
> install("C:/R/R local repository src/RcppArrayFire", configure.args = "--with-arrayfire=C:/Program Files/ArrayFire/v3/")

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Or tell me what I missed in my attempt to solve the problem. In my humble opinion, it is not normal to force the user to do such hard modifications of the source of a package in order to be able to install it. I have no idea how to do a "manual configuration" for the "configure script" that the source of this package has. So maybe one of its authors (or people knowing more about "Rcpp" settings) may advise me what to do. I'll be indebted to them...
Thank you by advance for your reply or answers.
PS: I may send you the last error message I received from R during the attempt to compile the package, but not here, because it is really very long. And I'm afraid to send a too long question.

I haven't done any work on RcppArrayFire for quite some time, so I am unsure in what shape it is. But it will not work on Windows, c.f. https://github.com/daqana/rcpparrayfire/issues/3.
